# SSRS Hyperlink expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I am wanting to understand if possible to set a conditional hyperlink expression in SSRS within the Action setting.

My code which works currently is

```
 =iif(First(Fields!IsHosted.Value, "ReportServer") = "Y",       First(Fields!ServerName.Value, "ReportServer"), Globals!ReportServerUrl) + 
"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" + Globals!ReportFolder + "/" +
code.GetTargetReportName("Student Performance Against Goal Drill") +
"&GoalCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!GoalCol.Value) + 
"&SectionCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!SectionCol.Value) +
"&TargetCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!TargetCol.Value) +
"&ItemCol=" + Cstr(Fields!Item.Value)
```

I simply want to say "If field B =0 then do nothing, else use the above. I am not familiar how to wrap this statement in the action.

Comment: The aim of this is to prevent the user from drilling down to the drilldown report when the value is 0 and will render an empty report.

Comment: What is the field you want to validate is not zero?

Comment: So on Field A is the drill action - there is another column (field B) - if Field B = 0 then the drill action on Field A should do nothing, else the drill action on Field A should drill as per the action.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `IIF()` functions:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!B.Value,"ReportServer") = 0,Nothing,
iif(First(Fields!IsHosted.Value, "ReportServer") = "Y",First(Fields!ServerName.Value, "ReportServer"), Globals!ReportServerUrl) + 
"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" + Globals!ReportFolder + "/" +
code.GetTargetReportName("Student Performance Against Goal Drill") +
"&GoalCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!GoalCol.Value) + 
"&SectionCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!SectionCol.Value) +
"&TargetCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!TargetCol.Value) +
"&ItemCol=" + Cstr(Fields!Item.Value)
)
```

I don't know what the dataset structure is but this could help you.

Comment: This is the URL modified however it reports that end of statement expected. Not sure where the missing syntax is.

Comment: =IIF(First(Fields!NoOfStudents.Value,"RSItemPerformanceAgainstGoal") = 0,Nothing,
iif(First(Fields!IsHosted.Value, "ReportServer") = "Y",First(Fields!ServerName.Value, "ReportServer"), Globals!ReportServerUrl) + 
"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" + Globals!ReportFolder + "/" +
code.GetTargetReportName("Student Performance Against Goal Drill") +
"&GoalCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!GoalCol.Value) + 
"&SectionCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!SectionCol.Value) +
"&TargetCol=" + Code.URLEncode(Parameters!TargetCol.Value) +
"&ItemCol=" + Cstr(Fields!Item.Value))
)

Comment: @jasonbarry, I've updated the expression, just deleted an additional parenthesis. Give it a try.

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Its reporting an invalid scope parameter

Comment: @jasonbarry, it seems there is an error in the scope of the `FIRST` functions. Check the second parameter i.e, dataset names you are passing  to the `FIRST` functions, be sure each paramater matches the name of one the datasets you have.

Comment: Ok have tested this again and the report deploys with no issue and the syntax of the expression is parsed correctly. However when navigating the report, no drill action is initiated even on the fields where there should be a drill-down action.

Comment: @jasonbarry, Are you using that expression in a textbox or tablix Action property? If the Action is disabled it seems  `First(Fields!NoOfStudents.Value,"RSItemPerformanceAgain‌​stGoal") = 0` is evaluating to true always. Check if that is the case.

Comment: This expression is within the action property of the textbox.

Comment: @jasonbarry, Without knowing the structure of your dataset and the tablix you are using I think the problem is that you are using fields out of the scope of the tablix.